# what is dojo equivalent of jquery's $(this) or $(JavaScript object)?

Tags: jquery, dojo

`$(this)` or `$(JavaScript object)` returns a javascript object wrapped in jquery object, hence making it a jquery object, which gives it additional functionalities?

What is its dojo's equivalent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dojo doesn't have a wrapper for objects as far as I know of. It has a wrapper for DOM nodes:

```
require([ "dojo/query" ], function(query) {
    query(document.getElementById("test")); // Adds extra features
});
```

You can then add extra features by importing one of these modules:

- dojo/NodeList-dom
- dojo/NodeList-data
- dojo/NodeList-traverse
- dojo/NodeList-manipulate
- dojo/NodeList-fx
- dojo/NodeList-html

There are probably equivalents in Dojo for the additional functionalities you want, but then you will have to give more information about which functionalities you really need.